# How to integrate an Android database in Drupal?

Tags: importing-exporting, database

How do I add an Android apps database contents to a Drupal site?

I have an Android app with a database having 3 tables. I also have a Drupal site with 3 content types as the 3 tables of apps databse.

What should I do so that the contents of apps database is imported to Drupal contents, so that each content type corresponds to the contents of the 3 tables in Android? Is there any module available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module for such kinds of imports. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

Especially the first bullet seems to be what you're looking for.

Consider refining your question to provide some more details of the database format of your Android app. E.g. is it a PDO-compliant DBMS? If so, and in case you'd want to consider it, it might be possible to use a co-existance setup also (= use Drupal to only 'display' your data residing in your Android app).